# Create newcommand where every argument has multiple characters

Tags: macros

How can I create a newcommand (for latex preamble, using lyx) which its arguments are more than one character?

Specifically, I'm trying to create myself a shortcut for the [*Rank–nullity theorem*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank%E2%80%93nullity_theorem) and tried to set the following latex preamble I wrote: (I've set `\Ima` command to `Im` text)

```
\newcommand{\dimthm}[2]{\dim{#1}=\dim{\Ima{#2}}+\dim{\ker{#2}}}
```

It works fine if every argument is only one character: `\dimthm VT` will produce:

```
dim V = dim Im T + dim ker T
```

But if for example my transformation is `LALA` I won't be able to get

```
dim V = dim Im LALA + dim ker LALA
```

Is it possible?

I've saw a few similar question over here, but couldn't make any solution work.

Comment: You know that you should use `\dimthm{VT}` then? Otherwise TeX/LaTeX just reads the `V` and ignores the `T` as macro argument to `\dimthm`

Comment: Oh you're right, I just automatically wrote it as I use the command in Lyx editor.

Comment: which proves that such editors LyX lead to lazyness ;-)

Comment: Which editor do you recommend? I just started with LyX since I heard of it and I was short in time to learn and needed to start quickly

Comment: I don't recommend those editors at all. Use vi or emacs or notepad etc.

Comment: You can use any [LaTeX editor or editor with LaTeX support](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/339/latex-editors-ides).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grouping with braces should help.  In this way, `V` is the first argument and `LALA` is the second.  However, one must remember that something like LALA will typeset as four consecutive math variables `L`, `A`, `L`, `A`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\def\Ima{\mathrm{Im}}
\newcommand{\dimthm}[2]{\dim{#1}=\dim{\Ima{#2}}+\dim{\ker{#2}}}
\begin{document}
$\dimthm VT$

$\dimthm V{LALA}$

$\dimthm {Howdy}{Ho}$
\end{document}
```